# Why am I getting strange tea cups icons in my inbox list view in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I get strange tea cups in my inbox in Thunderbird. Can anybody please explain me what this is? Google is not useful for this question. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those arent tea cups!  Zoom in and you will see they are eyes.  I think a zoom or font setting in Thunderbird is cutting them off a little.  The eyes symbolize "watch this thread" and are set/unset by hitting the W key.